# Acronym - Bold abbreviation without bold citation number

Tags: formatting, footnotes, bold, acronyms

I am using the `acronym` package and let it create a footnote with the explanation on the first use of my abbreviation.

However, at some parts I am using `\textbf{\ac{ISO-TP}}` which also makes the citation number bold. Is there a way to prevent this? Just switching `\textbf` and `\ac` doesn't work, of course.

**Edit:** Here is an example - I want "ISO-TP" bold and "ISO" normal, but both the "8" and the "9" normal. Not the "8" bold.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`acronym` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf):

> There are three lower-level macros controlling the output. Any acronym
>   printed by `\acs` is formatted by `\acsfont`. Similarly, unless the option
>   *footnote* is specified, `\acffont` handles the output of `\acf`, where the
>   included acronym goes through `\acfsfont` (and `\acsfont`).

```
\renewcommand*\acsfont{\textbf}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red!60!black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage,footnote]{acronym}
\renewcommand\acsfont{\textbf}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\ac{CDMA} \qquad\ac{CDMA}

\ac{test} \qquad\ac{test}

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[Text with the largest label]
 \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{test}{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
             Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

You can define a command in relation to `\textbf` which redefines `acsfont` local. In the following example I define `\formatac`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red!60!black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage,footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\formatac}[1]{%
\bgroup\renewcommand\acsfont{\textbf}%
\relax#1\relax\egroup\xspace}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\formatac{\ac{CDMA}} \qquad\ac{CDMA}

\ac{test} \qquad\ac{test}

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[Text with the largest label]
 \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{test}{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
             Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Output of the second MWE:

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you... this is my first time I work with LaTex, so I don't know how to re-write stuff in packages myself. :) It seems to work in most cases, but in some it doesn't. I can't tell any difference, however.

Comment: @jellyfish: I added a complete example and everything works well.

Comment: oooooh, I see. No, that's not what I wanted. Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough, sorry. I don't want ALL accronyms bold. I only want a few certain ones bold, which works fine if I just put a \textbf{} around. What I want is that the citation numbers stay normal and don't go bold with the acronym.

Comment: @jellyfish: I edited my post.

Comment: Wow! Now *this* is fancy, thank you very much! Never thought there would actually be a way! :)